# I have imageViews representing different colors.I want to change the color card of the color selected by the if else statement.How can i do that?

Tags: android, kotlin

**colorPickerB8FAC3 is an Imageview id and after click that cardview will be same color with imageview**

```
private fun pickColor(){
    binding.colorPickerB8FAC3.setOnClickListener {
        binding.colorPickerCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B8FAC3"))
    }

    binding.colorPickerBEB8FA.setOnClickListener {
        binding.colorPickerCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BEB8FA"))
    }

    binding.colorPickerFF9090.setOnClickListener {
        binding.colorPickerCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9090"))
    }

    binding.colorPickerFFE6AB.setOnClickListener {
        binding.colorPickerCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE6AB"))
    }

    binding.colorPickerFFFFCC.setOnClickListener {
        binding.colorPickerCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFCC"))
    }
}
```

**but I cannot determine which is the last color chosen here.**

```
private fun saveBtn(){
    binding.settingsButton.setOnClickListener {
        while (
            binding.colorPickerCardView.cardBackgroundColor -> #B8FAC3
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: please add more information about how these two are connected and what is the actual problem

Comment: hi.
binding.colorPickerCardView.cardBackgroundColor -> #B8FAC3 is a wrong code. 
After clicking the textview, the cardview takes the color of it.but for the switch case, I have to take the active cardview color and compare it with the rgb color color.Thus, I can save the selected color through the room data base and make it recycler view.